# gitosis: list all repositories

Tags: git

Is there a way to get a compact list of all git repositories managed by gitosis.

I'm looking for something similiar to

```
svn list url_to_repo
```

I know that I can have a look at `gitosis.conf`, but that's to wordy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put the following code into my `.bashrc`:

```
function repos
{
   gitosisDir="/cygdrive/c/Users/Ernst/Source/gitosis-admin"
   awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "[] "; ORS = "\n" } 
        /repo/ {print $2}' "$gitosisDir/gitosis.conf" | sed 's/[][]//g'
}
```

Now I can just type `repos` and get a handy list of all repositories defined in `gitosis.conf`.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know you can't check what repositories you have access to with gitosis, without checking the gitosis.conf file or without access to the gitosis repo dir (either remote or local)

You should use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) to fulfill that need.

Gitolite is easy to install and the usage is almost the same as gitosis (single user access, using a repository with a config file and keydir to configure the service, etc), but it allows setting permissions per branch (if you need to), sync with gitweb, and a bunch of other options (a lot of them actually!)

The best part is that you can send the 'info' command to the server using ssh and it will list the repositories you have access to.

e.g: The command

```
anUser@computer> ssh git@my-git-server info
```

Will show in the screen something like

```
hello anUser, the gitolite version here is v1.5.7-4-g270e0b9
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R+  W  Repo1
     R   W  Repo2
     R      Repo3
    @R_ @W_ testing
```